# R: problem with lmtest on macos with brew due to lemutls_w

Tags: r

while install.packages("lmtest") on a fully-updated macos M1 system with brew

```
clang -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.2_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c init.c -o init.o
/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/bin/gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c pan.f -o pan.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.2_1/lib/R/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/lib -L/opt/homebrew/lib -o lmtest.so init.o pan.o -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin22/12 -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/gcc -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current -lgfortran -lemutls_w -lquadmath -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.2_1/lib/R/lib -lR -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin22/12'
ld: library not found for -lemutls_w
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [lmtest.so] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3):

one way to fix the problem is

```
> sudo bash
# cd /opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/gcc
# ln -s aarch64-apple-darwin21 aarch64-apple-darwin22
```

it's a hack, of course.  not sure why the author and I have a mismatch here, but this makes it work again.

Comment: `brew reinstall gcc` also seems to fix it